# Can see Windows machines from mac but not Mac from Windows

Tags: mac, windows, network-user

I've tried all of the advice but none seems to work

I have an iMac M1 running Sonoma 14.4 and an older iMac running Windows 10 via Bootcamp.

From the M1 iMac, I can see the Windows machine and can access the files but cannot drag files from the M1 to the Mac running Windows 10

From the iMac running Windows 10, I cannot see the the M1 iMac at all. Both show they are connected to WORKGROUP.

File sharing is enabled on both machines

Comment: What is “all the advice” that did not work?  We don’t want to duplicate efforts.  Can you manually get the M1 Mac’s IP address and ping it?

Comment: You'll need to tell us a bit more about the File Sharing settings on the Mac. Have you set it to use SMB, and configured the options for Windows file sharing?

Comment: Do you have prevent tracking enabled.  It randomizes the MAC address and it might have something to do with it